# Provide S3 bucket access to Any Authenticated AWS user in the new console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to provide full access for "Any Authenticated AWS User" to my S3 Bucket. The old S3 console has an option as below to do this:

[image]

The new console doesn't have a similar option any more. I am switching to the old console now to enable this option but the old console is going to be inaccessible soon by Aug 31st 2017. Any idea how can i do this in the new Console ? If not a UI option , at least with a bucket policy ?

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to provide full access for "Any Authenticated AWS User" to my S3 Bucket.

**I *strongly* advise against that**. You are opening yourself up to an incredibly large number of potential issues.

What if somebody uploads 10PB of data to your bucket? Your bill would be at least $260k for that month.

What if somebody uploads copyrighted material (or any kind of illegal material) to your bucket? You would be responsible for the likely illegal distribution of copyrighted material.

Many, *many* companies are actively scanning their buckets to find those that have open write privileges and taking action to remediate that ASAP! Even some of the security related services from AWS will complain if you do that. As an example, Trusted Advisor has a built-in rule to detect and notify you against what you are trying to do.

If you describe the problem you are trying to solve, you might get betters suggestions.

Comment: Amazon will [send you a warning email](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/6ogmbp/interesting_email_from_aws_re_public_s3_buckets/) if you set a bucket to allow public _reads_. I imagine there's a similar warning for public write access.

Comment: Nope , never got an email. Had set public Access before

Comment: I believe "Any Authenticated AWS User" really meant "Any User Authenticated by IAM credentials in your account"... not any random person logged into AWS. So this isn't as open as it sounds.

Comment: @JohnEikenberry - that's not the case. Any Authenticated AWS User means exactly what the name suggests: any random person logged into AWS, on any account (not only the bucket owner's account). Here's the relevant documentation page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html - So, yes, it is WAY open! The difference between this and "public access" is that this requires authentication while public access requires no authentication. But still, it's completely open.

Comment: I just read that today when looking into it some more. I can't image a use case, so it seemed so unlikely that they would have that as an option.

Comment: @JohnEikenberry: one use case - suppose you want to share a file publicly, but you want to have very accurate tracking of who downloaded it from you. If the bucket had public read, anybody without authentication would be able to download the object; with the setting above, you would know exactly who downloaded the object from you. But yeah, I'm stretching a bit :) These days nobody should be using that. But that's been there for maybe 10 years, and it's unlikely that it's gonna be removed. Cheers!